# Attach PDF File in an Email

Tags: marketing-cloud, community, marketing-cloud-connect, marketingcloudapi

I need to attach a PDF file in an Email in Salesforce marketing cloud.
i use the function AttachFile() and i use an LINK of that PDF:

> ```
> %%[ 
> var @fileName, @fileAlias
> set @fileName = "https://UAT2.cs88.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/9E0000000XV0/a/9E0000009hqy/C0suCcZI_iTpItmAFsKtkoQ6Kn42Jl1e2SAktZxv8p8.pdf"
> set @fileAlias = "Support_V0.2.pdf"
> AttachFile('HTTP', @fileName,@fileAlias)
> ]%%
> ```

when a send the Email I have the pdf attach but it contain only 2Ko knowing that the real size of the File is 459Ko, and when I try to open the PDF I have an error message "Failed to load the PDF document."

Comment: Is your pdf file publicly accessible ?

Comment: Yes and the URL is public

Comment: I can't access your URL. Also, I ran your exact same script with a public jpg and it worked fine. Retry with another public pdf url (not linked to your Salesforce account)

Comment: Okay thank you i'll try with another URL

Comment: Hello @ZakBen I try another URL and its work 
the URL I use first is an URL generated in Service cloud and unfortunately this URL is directly pointed in the fil he point in a page that redirects you to the file
I don't know if there is another amp script function that allow me to get the File from this URL ??